How to make Facebook Prophet produce reproducible results?
I'm using Facebook Prophet for timeseries forecasting and I see that it is producing slightly different forecast results when running it locally vs on the pipeline, it is running inside a Docker container so it should be the same environment.
I looked at the the result after calling prophet.fit() and I see that there is a difference in the "params", basically there is a difference in all of the parameters and I'm guessing this is the reason behind the slightly different forecast results that I'm getting.
Is there a way to make it reproducible?

